# Multithreading won't work as expected

Tags: c++, multithreading, winsock

I have a problem with my program. I wanted it to have two threads, one of them listening for connections, and the other one receiving data from them... Unfortunately, it acts strangely. It will ignore my cout and cin usage everywhere in the code, so I can't even debug it. May I ask that someone sheds some light on it? Thank you in advance.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cstdlib>

int ConnectionNum, Port=4673;
WSADATA wsaData;
SOCKET Connections[256];

DWORD WINAPI ReceiveThread(LPVOID iValue)
{
    //this is going to be receiving TCP/IP packets, as soon as the connection works
}

DWORD WINAPI ListenThread(LPVOID iValue) //this thread is supposed to listen for new connections and store them in an array
{
    SOCKET ListeningSocket;
    SOCKET NewConnection;
    SOCKADDR_IN ServerAddr;
    SOCKADDR_IN ClientAddr;
    int ClientAddrLen;

    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
    ListeningSocket=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    ServerAddr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    ServerAddr.sin_port=htons(Port);
    ServerAddr.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    bind(ListeningSocket, (SOCKADDR*)&ServerAddr, sizeof(ServerAddr));

    if(listen(ListeningSocket, 5)!=0)
    {
        cout << "Could not begin listening for connections.";
        return 0;
    }

    ConnectionNum=0;

    while(ConnectionNum<256)
    {
        Connections[ConnectionNum]=accept(ListeningSocket, (SOCKADDR*)&ClientAddr, &ClientAddrLen);
        ConnectionNum++;

        cout << "New connection.";
    }
}

int main()
{
    HANDLE hThread1,hThread2;
    DWORD dwGenericThread;
    char lszThreadParam[3];

    hThread1=CreateThread(NULL, 0, ListenThread, &lszThreadParam, 0, &dwGenericThread);

    if(hThread1==NULL)
    {
        DWORD dwError=GetLastError();
        cout<<"SCM:Error in Creating thread"<<dwError<<endl ;
        return 0;
    }

    hThread2=CreateThread(NULL, 0, ReceiveThread, &lszThreadParam, 0, &dwGenericThread);

    if(hThread2==NULL)
    {
        DWORD dwError=GetLastError();
        cout<<"SCM:Error in Creating thread"<<dwError<<endl ;
        return 0;
    }

    system("pause"); //to keep the entire program from ending
}
```

Comment: what is the strange behavior ?

Comment: It ignores all cout and cin calls everywhere in the code, it simply won't call them. I put a cout and a cin in the beginning of the main function, it didn't show up either.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any *cin* calls here. As for the calls to *cout*, you may have to flush the output, as it is being called in a separate thread. You can do this by simply calling *std::endl*:

```
cout << "New connection." << std::endl;
```

Comment: +1 This has been my problem a few times. Also instead of "endl" you can use "flush" if you don't want the actual endline character.

Comment: Thank you for both your answers. I've been trying the cin, but removed it. Activation the console worked, thanks. I am still having problems with connection, but I think I can handle it. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason that your `cout` calls aren't showing up is possibly because you're supplying the wrong parameters to the linker. Are you specifying `/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE` ? (System tab of the Linker properties). If not then you're not telling the operating system to create a console for the program, you may be telling it it's a windows program, and if you program doesn't have a console then you wont see your programs `cout` output...

Once you can see your debug...

I assume you are connecting to your test program from a client of some sort? Nothing will happen until you connect to your program which will cause the call to Accept() to return.

By the way, `system("pause");` is probably the worst way to achieve what you want but I assume you're only doing that because you can't get `cin` to work...